# Creating a Bank program

Tags: java

I am almost done with an assignment. I am creating a Bank program, and I have almost everything done. The part that I am stuck on is the transactions part. I have to create a function `public String getTransactionInfo(int n)` which returns the last n transactions of a bank account. I cannot seem to figure this part out. i have a variable `private int numOfTransactions` and I tried incorporating that into the function, but it didn't work. this is what I tried.

```
public String gettransactionInfo(int n)
{
    numOfTransactions = n;
    return n;
}
```

that did not work. cannot figure out how to return this is a string. any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Bank myBank = new Bank();

    int user_choice = 2;

    do {
        //display menu to user
        //ask user for his choice and validate it (make sure it is between 1 and 6)
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1) Open a new bank account");
        System.out.println("2) Deposit to a bank account");
        System.out.println("3) Withdraw to bank account");
        System.out.println("4) Print short account information");
        System.out.println("5) Print the detailed account information including last transactions");
        System.out.println("6) Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter choice [1-6]: ");
        user_choice = s.nextInt();
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Enter a customer name");
                    String cn = s.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter a opening balance");
                    double d = s.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Account was created and it has the following number: " + myBank.openNewAccount(cn, d));
                    break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int an = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter a deposit amount");
                    double da = s.nextDouble();
                    myBank.depositTo(an, da);
                    break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int acn = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter a withdraw amount");
                    double wa = s.nextDouble();
                    myBank.withdrawFrom(acn, wa);
                    break;
            case 4: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int anum = s.nextInt();
                    myBank.printAccountInfo(anum);
                    break;
            //case 5: ... break;
        }
}
while (user_choice != '6');
}

static class Bank {
private BankAccount[] accounts;     // all the bank accounts at this bank
private int numOfAccounts;      // the number of bank accounts at this bank

// Constructor: A new Bank object initially doesn’t contain any accounts.
public Bank() {
    accounts = new BankAccount[100];
    numOfAccounts = 0;
    }

// Creates a new bank account using the customer name and the opening balance given as parameters
// and returns the account number of this new account. It also adds this account into the account list
// of the Bank calling object.
public int openNewAccount(String customerName, double openingBalance) {

    BankAccount b = new BankAccount(customerName, openingBalance);
    accounts[numOfAccounts] = b;
    numOfAccounts++;
    return b.getAccountNum();
}

// Withdraws the given amount from the account whose account number is given. If the account is
// not available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void withdrawFrom(int accountNum, double amount) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
            accounts[i].withdraw(amount);
            System.out.println("Amount withdrawn successfully");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
    }

// Deposits the given amount to the account whose account number is given. If the account is not
// available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void depositTo(int accountNum, double amount) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
            accounts[i].deposit(amount);
            System.out.println("Amount deposited successfully");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
}

// Prints the account number, the customer name and the balance of the bank account whose
// account number is given. If the account is not available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void printAccountInfo(int accountNum) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
                if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
                    System.out.println(accounts[i].getAccountInfo());
                    return;
                }
            }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
}

// Prints the account number, the customer number and the balance of the bank account whose
// account number is given, together with last n transactions on that account. If the account is not
// available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void printAccountInfo(int accountNum, int n) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
                        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
                            System.out.println(accounts[i].getAccountInfo());
                            System.out.println(accounts[i].getTransactionInfo(n));
                            return;
                        }
                    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
    }

}





  static class BankAccount{

       private int accountNum;
       private String customerName;
       private double balance;
       private double[] transactions;
       private int numOfTransactions;
       private  static int noOfAccounts=0;

       public String getAccountInfo(){
           return "Account number: " + accountNum + "\nCustomer Name: " + customerName + "\nBalance:" + balance +"\n";
       }

       public String getTransactionInfo(int n)
       {
            numOfTransactions = n;
            return n;

        }

       public BankAccount(String abc, double xyz){
         customerName = abc;
         balance = xyz;
         noOfAccounts ++;
         accountNum = noOfAccounts;
         transactions = new double[100];
         transactions[0] = balance;
         numOfTransactions = 1;
       }

    public int getAccountNum(){
        return accountNum;
    }
    public void deposit(double amount){

        if (amount<=0) {
            System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
        } else {
            balance = balance + amount;
            transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
            numOfTransactions++;
        }
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if (amount<=0){
             System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
         }
        else
        {
            if (balance < amount) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
            } else {
                balance = balance - amount;
                transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
                numOfTransactions++;
            }
        }
    }

}//end of class
}
```

Comment: I assume this is homework, right? You didn't post commercial bank program source code here, right?

Comment: correct. this is homework

Comment: but it didn't work? explain what didn't work.

Comment: I think you posted this question earlier too! Isn't it?

Comment: but i assume what you want is String out = Integer.toString(n)

Comment: @SeanF as you would be able to tell, i receive an error message incompatible types. cannot seem to think of a way to figure out how to solve this one last part of returning the last n transactions as a string

Comment: @Jared `homework` tag is deprecated.

Comment: @madth3 Thanks for clearing that up, haven't been here in a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return the number of transactions as a String, as opposed to the integer (which you have it stored as), then you want to convert the integer to a String.

In Java, you would do so via:

```
Integer.toString(numOfTransactions)
```

Side note: Out of curiosity, in your program, why are you doing this?

```
public String gettransactionInfo(int n)
{
    numOfTransactions = n;
    return n;
}
```

That is inefficient and wrong since you are setting the numberOfTransactions to the n value. That functionality, by convention is put in a setter method, as opposed to a getter method - which is what your implementation is supposed to do.

Ideally, it should be:

```
public String gettransactionInfo()
{
    return Integer.toString(numOfTransactions);
}
```

EDIT:

As per the comments, the correct thing to do would be to return an index from the transactions array, corresponding to index n.

Where, in this case the transactions array should be a String array.

EDIT 2:

In the case where you use a separate string array, you would update it (depending on the transaction) as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Bank myBank = new Bank();

    int user_choice = 2;

    do {
        //display menu to user
        //ask user for his choice and validate it (make sure it is between 1 and 6)
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1) Open a new bank account");
        System.out.println("2) Deposit to a bank account");
        System.out.println("3) Withdraw to bank account");
        System.out.println("4) Print short account information");
        System.out.println("5) Print the detailed account information including last transactions");
        System.out.println("6) Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter choice [1-6]: ");
        user_choice = s.nextInt();
        switch (user_choice) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Enter a customer name");
                    String cn = s.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter a opening balance");
                    double d = s.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Account was created and it has the following number: " + myBank.openNewAccount(cn, d));
                    break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int an = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter a deposit amount");
                    double da = s.nextDouble();
                    myBank.depositTo(an, da);
                    break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int acn = s.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter a withdraw amount");
                    double wa = s.nextDouble();
                    myBank.withdrawFrom(acn, wa);
                    break;
            case 4: System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    int anum = s.nextInt();
                    myBank.printAccountInfo(anum);
                    break;
           case 5:  System.out.println("Enter a account number");
                    anum = s.nextInt();
                    myBank.printTransactionInfo(anum);
                    break;
          default: System.out.println("Invalid option. Please try again.");

        }
}
while (user_choice != '6');
}

static class Bank {
private BankAccount[] accounts;     // all the bank accounts at this bank
private int numOfAccounts;      // the number of bank accounts at this bank

    //Constructor: A new Bank object initially doesnâ€™t contain any accounts.
public Bank() {
    accounts = new BankAccount[100];
    numOfAccounts = 0;
    }

// Creates a new bank account using the customer name and the opening balance given as parameters
// and returns the account number of this new account. It also adds this account into the account list
// of the Bank calling object.
public int openNewAccount(String customerName, double openingBalance) {

    BankAccount b = new BankAccount(customerName, openingBalance);
    accounts[numOfAccounts] = b;
    numOfAccounts++;
    return b.getAccountNum();
}

// Withdraws the given amount from the account whose account number is given. If the account is
// not available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void withdrawFrom(int accountNum, double amount) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
            accounts[i].withdraw(amount);
            System.out.println("Amount withdrawn successfully");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
    }

// Deposits the given amount to the account whose account number is given. If the account is not
// available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void depositTo(int accountNum, double amount) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
            accounts[i].deposit(amount);
            System.out.println("Amount deposited successfully");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
}

// Prints the account number, the customer name and the balance of the bank account whose
// account number is given. If the account is not available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void printAccountInfo(int accountNum) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
                if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
                    System.out.println(accounts[i].getAccountInfo());
                    return;
                }
            }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
}

public void printTransactionInfo(int accountNum) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
                if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
                    System.out.println(accounts[i].getAccountInfo());
                    System.out.println("Last transaction: " + accounts[i].getTransactionInfo(accounts[i].getNumberOfTransactions()-1));
                    return;
                }
            }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
}


// Prints the account number, the customer number and the balance of the bank account whose
// account number is given, together with last n transactions on that account. If the account is not
// available at the bank, it should print a message.
public void printAccountInfo(int accountNum, int n) {
    for (int i =0; i<numOfAccounts; i++) {
                        if (accountNum == accounts[i].getAccountNum()  ) {
                            System.out.println(accounts[i].getAccountInfo());
                            System.out.println(accounts[i].getTransactionInfo(n));
                            return;
                        }
                    }
    System.out.println("Account number not found.");
    }

}
    static class BankAccount{

       private int accountNum;
       private String customerName;
       private double balance;
       private double[] transactions;
       private String[] transactionsSummary;
       private int numOfTransactions;
       private  static int noOfAccounts=0;

       public String getAccountInfo(){
           return "Account number: " + accountNum + "\nCustomer Name: " + customerName + "\nBalance:" + balance +"\n";
       }

       public String getTransactionInfo(int n)
       {
            String transaction = transactionsSummary[n];
            if (transaction == null) {
                return "No transaction exists with that number.";
            }
            else {
                return transaction;
            }
        }

       public BankAccount(String abc, double xyz){
         customerName = abc;
         balance = xyz;
         noOfAccounts ++;
         accountNum = noOfAccounts;
         transactions = new double[100];
         transactionsSummary = new String[100];
         transactions[0] = balance;
         transactionsSummary[0] = "A balance of : $" + Double.toString(balance) + " was deposited.";
         numOfTransactions = 1;
       }

    public int getAccountNum(){
        return accountNum;
    }

    public int getNumberOfTransactions() {
        return numOfTransactions;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount){

        if (amount<=0) {
            System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
        } else {
            balance = balance + amount;
            transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
            transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = "$" + Double.toString(amount) + " was deposited.";
            numOfTransactions++;
        }
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if (amount<=0){
             System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
         }
        else
        {
            if (balance < amount) {
                System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
            } else {
                balance = balance - amount;
                transactions[numOfTransactions] = amount;
                transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = "$" + Double.toString(amount) + " was withdrawn.";
                numOfTransactions++;
            }
        }
    }

    }//end of class
}
```

Comment: the teacher wants us to have `int n` being passed as an arguement

Comment: Okay, I see what's going on - as per the other comments. Let me edit this better.

Comment: @beginnerprogrammer: The "private double[] transactions" in BankAccount class holds the key to your problem. I think you will need to get the most recent "n" transactions from that array.

Comment: Update: edit scrapped - NirmalGeo and Manish have the right idea.

Comment: the declaration of the array was given to me by the teacher. and that is how the teacher had it

Comment: Okay. Well, that means you probably have to create __another__ array that holds the transaction (as per NirmalGeo's answer) summaries, and update it as you would the `transactions` array. That way, both correspond to the same transaction, and as such, the index n, would also refer to the same transaction stored in `transactions`.

Comment: And, why do this as opposed to simply converting to the values from the `transactions` array to a String? Because the transactions array lacks state. That is, as is, you can't tell if there was a deposit or withdrawal just looking at that particular index. However, you can tell the state by comparing the values of the previous index which will tell you what transaction occurred, and that can be returned.

Comment: The only reason I am mentioning doing it like this is that I don't know the requirements of your problem, and how the solution has to be implemented. And, since you mentioned that your teacher gave you an implementation, then I think determining the transaction by comparing the current vs the previous indices of the transactions array is ideally the way to go. Either way, your call.

Comment: ok. thats the part where i'm stuck on. how to incorporate this new array with the array i currently have

Comment: You would do so by adding the array (henceforth called `transactionsSummary` as a private variable in the definition of the BankAccount class: `private String[] transactionsSummary`. And then in all places where `transactions` is created, updated or modified, you create a String with a summary of the transaction (i.e. created, deposited or withdrawn) and the balance.

Comment: That way, `transactionsSummary` now has the same size as transactions, and the same index n, can be used to access the transactions in both. Just in this case, `transactionsSummary` will be more informative. The side effect of this is that you really be using the `transactions` array - making it more or less useless in this case. And, considering that this is an assignment where you have to use this implementation, it suggests that you have to determine state from the `transactions` array and __not__ use a separate array from here. But, I could be mistaken. That's my opinion anyway.

Comment: so I would implement the `transactionsSummary` into lets say my deposit function to create a summary of the transaction correct?

Comment: i'm sorry that I'm not able to understand this all. i'm just a beginner, and this doesn't come easy to me at all. but i really appreciate your patience and your breakdown descriptions that you are providing

Comment: in the constructor is this a correct statement to have in there.`transactionsSummary = new String[100]`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I forgot to mention that. My apologies.

Comment: its ok. when i typed in the code in the deposit and withdraw functions, i receive an error message saying `method Double.toString() is not applicable (actual and formal arguement lists differ in length)
method Double.toString(double) is not applicable.(actual argument double[] cannot be converted to double by ethod invocation conversion)`

Comment: also, if I change the code to `transactionsSummary[numOfTransactions] = Double.toString(amount);` I can get it to compile. But when i run it and I select option 5 to display it with the summary, my output for the transactioninfo is null

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25753/discussion-between-jrd1-and-beginnerprogrammer)

Answer (score 4):

I think the correct solution to your problem will be something like this:

```
    public String gettransactionInfo(int n)
{
  //Traverse the "transactions" array in *reverse* order
  //In For loop start with transactions.length, and decrement by 1 "n" times
  // Append the transaction amount to a String
 // Return the string.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public String gettransactionInfo(int n)
{
    numOfTransactions = n;
    return n;
}
```

Hehe! What are you exactly trying to do here? :) ... You messed up the rvalue and lvalue, but that's not related to the answer.

The key is to have a String Array in the class. Every time a transaction happens append the transaction details to the array..... Then gettransactionInfo should print the last n details in the string...

e.g.

```
transInfo[0] = "A deposited 30K"
transInfo[1] = "B withdrew 20K"
transInfo[2] = "C deposited 5k"
```

Last 1 transaction displays the last entry in the string "C deposited 5k"

Comment: ok. i can't seem to really think this completely through. i see what you are seeing, but translating that into coding is where i'm having trouble. i would use a for loop saying something like `for(int i=0; i<transactions.length; i++)` but can't really think of how to append the details in the for loop

Comment: Are you familiar with string concatenation? If not, look it up.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an integer to a String:

```
String out = Integer.toString(n);
```

Comment: IMHO, last "n" transactioninfo should return the details of transaction rather than the transaction count.

Comment: @SeanF - I really doubt if that's what OP wants. It'll make that method the most absurdest method ever.

Comment: @R.J and then op accepted that top answer when it was still only this

Answer (score 0):

You description of case 5 is

> Print the detailed account information including last transactions

Just returning the number of transactions as a string is not going to achieve that.

You need to store every transaction as it happens in the transactions array in your BankAccount class and then get the last n values in that array in the `gettransactionInfo()` function.

**EDIT:**

And btw, you have forgotten to call the `openNewAccount()` function

Comment: the `openNewAccount()` function is being called. it's in the last println statement. you have to scroll to the right to see it though. but it is there

Answer (score 0):

Convert primitive int to its wrapper class and call its `toString()` method

`public String gettransactionInfo(int n) {
    return new Integer(n).toString();
}`

Comment: thats helpful, but I have to also include the transaction details. which i am currently trying to work on.

Comment: Iterate and get transaction Info for each transaction. Append it in a `StringBuffer` and call toString()

Comment: which would require a for loop in the `getTransactionInfo(int n)` correct?

Comment: Yes add for loop in `getTransactionInfo(int n)`